# `go install` adds record in `go.mod`

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm a bit confused about how Go modules work on installing binaries using `go install`.

I tried to install (https://github.com/joho/godotenv) binary by executing `go install github.com/joho/godotenv/cmd/godotenv` and I found out that it adds a record in the `go.mod`. 
I'm lost as we don't use this package in the code and after running `go mod tidy` it gets deleted (as it is not it the code).

Can someone explain is it expected behaviour of go modules? 
Secondly, how I could avoid adding it to the `go.mod` as we only need to install and execute the binary?

Thanks.

Go version: `go version go1.13.4 darwin/amd64`

Comment: "Can someone explain is it expected behaviour of go modules?" Roughly: Most invocations of the `go` tool "inside" a module checks, updates go.{mod,sum} which is obvious for `build`, `test`, `get` and most of `mod`. Now think what `go install <modulename>/path/to/modulepackage` does: It builds a package from the current module and installs it; updating go.* on the way. The fact that you installed some command from an unrelated package is secondary here. Just `go install` stuff from /tmp instead from "inside" the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Command go: The go.mod file:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-The_go_mod_file)

> The go command automatically updates go.mod each time it uses the module graph, to make sure go.mod always accurately reflects reality and is properly formatted.

The go tool will update `go.mod` automatically when it detects dependencies are inaccurate when performing a build.

When you install `github.com/joho/godotenv/cmd/godotenv` from your module, this install requires at least the package in question being built / installed (and also its dependencies, transitively).

You may safely run `go mod tidy` to undo the recording of this "one-time" dependency.

In general if you want to disallow the go tool to update the `go.mod` file, you may use the `-mod=readonly` flag, but that would fail `go install` (*"can't load package: package xxx: import lookup disabled by -mod=readonly"*). You can read more about this here: [Go Wiki: Go modules: Can I control when go.mod gets updated and when the go tools use the network to satisfy dependencies?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-control-when-gomod-gets-updated-and-when-the-go-tools-use-the-network-to-satisfy-dependencies)

Alternatively, if you want to avoid this, build / install your tools outside of your module. You may use a "dummy" module for this.

Comment: You can also use `env GO111MODULE=off go install <package>`.